# Using JBL Reflect Flow Pro under linux

Tags: gnome, pulseaudio, bluetooth

I'm trying to use my new JBL Reflect Flow Pro bluetooth headphones under my Manjaro Linux distribution / Gnome. I am able to connect them via bluetooth and they show as "connected" in the bluetooth settings, but I am unable to select them in the audio tab - they don't show up as output or input device. They also show up as connected in `bluetoothctl paired-devices`.

Looking into the journalctl, I see this entry:

`Dez 15 14:08:08 t590 bluetoothd[1202]: src/device.c:search_cb() 48:BA:FF:xx:xx:xx: error updating services: Host is down (112)`

Besides that, I'm at a loss on how to debug this issue further. From what I know, the bluetooth driver has to forward a set of capabilities to pulseaudio, so that pulseaudio knows that there is a new audio device to route to?

Comment: Is the device not only connected, but also trusted? Have you tried restarting (power-cycling) the headphones? Suggested in https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Bluetooth_headset#Headset_via_Bluez5/PulseAudio and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023032/bluetooth-connection-host-is-down respectively.